# How to divide column values of a spreadsheet into ranges in an better way?

Tags: design-patterns, spreadsheet

Its a kind of vague question. I have a spreadsheet, with few hundred columns. Each column represents values of one variable which is continuous. I want to create a second spreadsheet with same number of columns but the values of all the continuous variables should be mapped to some ranges. Ranges of each variable are different.

e.g.

```
Col 1   Col 2   Col 3
0.41    123     12:45
0.53    345     05:23
0.57    354     09:23
0.89    687     09:34
```

should become:

```
Col 1   Col 2   Col 3
0.40    125     12:00
0.50    350     05:00
0.50    350     09:00
0.80    675     09:00
```

I know that I can do it with normal if-else loops while checking column number. All I am thinking is if an additional column is added somewhere is in-between, it will force me to do lot of changes. Is there any design pattern which is generally used for this? any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this is a vague question. Why don't you give these columns some meaningful names ("height", "length", "weight", whatever), and maintain a set of constants in your code that specifies which name corresponds to which numbered column. That way, if the column layout changes, you just need to change a single constant.

Comment: That's a really good idea! Thanks Oli! And then I think can keep some sort of map where the ranges for a column_name are stored. Btw, the idea which you have suggested, is it some specific design pattern?

Comment: @10101010: Not really.  It's just following the principle that [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) should be avoided, in general.